# Which state do I vote in and how do I do it? (USA)

Tags: usa, us-citizens

I'm a US citizen living in the UK and am looking forward to voting in this year's election, if I can figure it out.

I was living in Pennsylvania for five years and then to do my visa I moved in with my parents for a month and a half in Georgia before moving to the UK. My driver's license and US mail all goes to Georgia, but I was last registered to vote in Pennsylvania, so I am wondering if I get an absentee in Pennsylvania or do I change my voting registration to Georgia and then get an absentee.

Any help with what's appropriate would be useful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See https://www.fvap.gov/.

You are supposed to vote in the state in which you were last domiciled, which doesn't have to be the last state in which you were registered to vote.  My guess is that this is Georgia, since you took a Georgia driver's license.  On the other hand, you could probably argue that your stay in Georgia does not establish it as your domicile since it was intended to be temporary.  I think therefore that you can choose either state.